# weak topology and weak* topology on $L^1, L^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose $L^1(I)$ is the primal space and $L^{\infty}(I)$ is the dual. Could I simultaneously define weak topology on $L^1(I)$ with respect to $L^{\infty}(I)$ and define weak or weak* topology on $L^{\infty}(I)$ with respect to $L^1(I)$  and use these definitions simultaneously?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. There is a weak topology on $L^\infty$; it is the coarsest topology on $L^\infty$ such that all bounded linear functionals are continuous. There is also a weak star topology on $L^\infty$; it is the coarsest topology on $L^\infty$ such that all bounded linear functionals of the form $T_f(L)=L(f)$ for $f \in L^1$ are continuous.

Comment: Written this way, it is not hard to understand that the weak star topology is at least as coarse as the weak topology. In certain situations, they coincide (for instance they coincide when we start with $L^p$ with $p \in (1,\infty)$). In this situation, if we have choice and a "rich enough" measure space (e.g. the Lebesgue measure space), the weak star topology is strictly coarser than the weak topology. But both are meaningful topologies.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand much better.

Comment: If a set is weak$^*$ compact with respect to its weak$^*$ topology, would the intersection of the same set with a closed subspace of the original space remain weak$^*$ compact ?

Comment: Do you specifically mean *subspace* or *subset*? The result is not true if you mean "subset", because for instance a sequence with constant positive norm can converge in weak star sense to zero. I'm not sure what happens in the subspace case.

Answer (score 2):

The topologies induced by the dual pairing $\sigma:L^1\times L^\infty \to \mathbb R$, defined by
$$
\sigma(u,v) = \int_I uv\ dx
$$
make them topological vector spaces with weak and weak-star topology:

$L^1$ supplied with topology induced by seminorms $p_v(u):=|\sigma(u,v)|$ 
coincides with $L^1$ supplied with the weak topology.

This follows from the fact that the mapping $v\mapsto f_v$, $f_v(u)=\int_I uv \ dx$, is an isometry between $L^\infty(I)$ and $L^1(I)^*$.

Comment: Good idea.  The only reason we distinguish "weak" and "weak*" is that we know $L^\infty$ is the dual space of the Banach space $L^1$.  There is a general theory (due to Mackey?) with a pairing $E \times F \to \mathbb R$, with corresponding topologies.  Called perhaps $\sigma(E,F), \sigma(F,E)$ or in Kelley-Namioka $w(E,F), w(F,E)$.